# Upgrading from jsf 2.1 to jsf 2.2 in netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jsf-2.2

I want to us jsf 2.2's file upload feature in my current project. I'm using maven for all of my jsf dependencies. Here is my dependency code:

```
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I cannot use `<h:fileUpload/>` tag in my xhtml page.

[image]

I'm using netbeans 7.2.1 and when I go to my project's properties then Frameworks it shows:

[image]

What I want is to use external jsf library that I downloaded with maven in project. How to change it to jsf 2.2 that I downloaded by maven?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but are you aware of the change in XML namespace since JSF 2.2? And, why specifically an old Mojarra 2.2 version? It's currently already at 2.2.8.

Comment: @BalusC I didn't know that change in XML namespace. What is it? I just upgraded jsf to 2.2.8 and still the same.

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.0-2.2.2 had a bug in supporting old `java.sun.com` XML namespace. Given that Mojarra 2.2.8 still doesn't work, it must be a Netbeans thing. To exclude one and other, what Mojarra version is being printed in webapp's startup log?

Comment: Okay thanks. I also think it is because of Netbeans. In the server log it says "Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context".

Comment: Ah, and when you open the page in browser, the upload thing is just there? Then it's definitely Netbeans who's being jerking with false errors. You could ignore the error or try upgrading to a JSF 2.2 aware version, if any.